# Animate two div's in same direction, one after the other

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide, scrollto

I have searched for this, but the best answer that has been given is 'Wrap a div around your items and then add your animate/scroll to that'. I agree, that would be a quick easy solution to my problem, however, i can't, unfortunately, wrap a div around my div's as i have a specific problem which requires me to animate each of my div's separate. I'll elaborate...

I have a div called 'highlight' which has some tiles in it in two rows, with 5 tiles in each row to form a grid. This is in what i call a 'Ribbon' which is a panel at the bottom of my page which has a container div around all the highlight tiles with a specified width with overflow hidden, allowing my content to be loaded and hidden and slide across when using the 'previous' or 'next' buttons on my pager. My code looks something like the following:

```
    <div class="ribbon-display">
      <div class="display-container clearfix">
       <div id="highlight">
         <div class="top-row clearfix">                                     
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
          <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
          <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
         </div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
          <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
          <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
       </div>
       <div id="highlight" class="new-highlight">
         <div class="top-row clearfix">                                     
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
          <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
          <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
         </div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
          <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
      <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
          <div class="ribbon-tile"></div>
       </div>
      </div>            
    </div>
```

What i am doing is loading 10 tiles at a time. Then, when the 'next' button is clicked, an ajax call is made to pull in the next 10 tiles. These are then appended to my content within my container div as a new 'highlight' div. Thus meaning, i now have two 'highlight' divs containing 10 tiles adjacent to each other. I can then scroll these both across to the left using the jquery 'animate' function to alter the 'left' position of the elements. When i do that however, the first highlight panel slides faster to the left than the next highlight panel next to it. Meaning that there is a gap in the slide, rather than sliding plush next each other. Much how can you do if all your slide content tiles are preloaded and just shown/hidden with the slide....

So my question is, how can i get these two div's to slide to the left at the same time, one directly after the other at the same speed? As i stated, i have explored using the animate function and altering the left position, like so....

```
$('#highlight').animate(
  {left:'-=971'},
  30000
);
$('.new-highlight').animate(
  {left:'-=971'},
  200
);
```

And also tried altering the leftScroll paramater in the animate function, and altering the speeds of each highlight div to try and slow the first one down to fake the animation looking slick. Anyone had experience with trying to do this? Can i use the 'scrollLeft' function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated here! thanks in advance guys!

Craig

Comment: In the future, please try to post questions that are much more concise and to the point, we do not need to see 30 lines of html gibberish, nor do we need to hear a long story about how things should work. Just post in as few words as possible, exactly what you want to know about.

Comment: Sorry mate, First ever post! I will take your criticism on board and improve my future posts. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any possible way you could make a gif, or a flash animation or a video explaining what you are looking for? it seems to be very ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You can daisy chain by using the delay function.

```
$('#highlight').animate({left:'-=971'},30000);
$('.new-highlight').delay(30000).animate({left:'-=971'},200);
```

Please note that it's milliseconds... you're making the animation taking 30 seconds! :)

"how can i get these two div's to slide to the left at the same time, one directly after the other at the same speed?"

At the same time or after each other? these are two different things :)

Here's a fiddle as i'm unsure about your animation intentions :)
http://jsfiddle.net/NZkf8/

Comment: Haha, yeah, i added the super long duration to that animate to test if i can slow the first div down, so don't worry, i won't be leaving that in there!! :)

What i want to do is animate both of these divs at the same time, but have them follow each other across, at the same speed. What is happening, is the #highlight div is sliding across faster than the .new-highlight, meaning the there is a gap between them. I don't want this gap, i want them to slide across next to each other. Does that make sense? Do you know how i can achieve this?

thanks,
Craig

Comment: could you possibly just apply a class to both of them and then just do $('.new-class').animate(...)?

Comment: I'm not sure i fully understand how you want the items to animate - please correct me if i'm wrong.

They both have to move to the left at the same time, at the same speed? I can't see your CSS code but if you're running the same animation on both items they should move equally fast. As long as the length moved and the time it has to move in is the same for both, they should animate identically. If you're moving an item 200 px in 1 second it will move as fast as an item moving 400px in 2 seconds.

Comment: Added a fiddle for better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a 'finished' function to the animate method, which will be called when the first finishes.

```
$('#highlight').animate({left:'-=971'},30000, function(){
  $('.new-highlight').animate(
    {left:'-=971'},
    200
  );
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. However this isn't the solution i am looking for. I don't want the second div (.new-highlight)to animate after the first one has animated, but rather both at the same time, with (.new-highlight) div following the #highlight div directly so i have a smooth transition? It's quite hard to explain what i want without going through an example. Anyone know what i'm after and have any ideas how to tackle this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're looking for... but its possible that you can achieve this effect of 'following' by setting an interval that causes the second div to animate to the location of the first div.. O_o

like this:

```
var follow = setInterval(function(){
  $('.new-highlight').animate(
    {left : $('#highlight').position().left},
    1000
  );
},1000)

$('#highlight').animate(
  {left:'-=971'},
  30000,
  function(){
    window.clearInterval(follow)
  }
);
```

You might try playing with both 1000's. if you make the second one 500, then every second, the second one will travel half the distance between the two wen it starts to move.

> I made this its own answer because my tactic is very different, and my
>   previous post could still be valid for people who are looking for help
>   on this topic.